# BreezeJS truncating the values of umapped properties

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I've been using BreezeJS v 1.4.11 in a project and all was working fine. Then I updated it to v1.4.13 and now I have a problem with unmapped properties. I know I shouldn't have messed with something that was working!

I have a couple of read-only decimal properties on my EF classes. They are calculated on the server side and returned correctly across the wire. I've checked this in Fiddler and in the developer tools in Chrome.

The property values are passed back to the client in the JSON result but don't appear as defined properties in the metadata from the server. This is understandable and so in the client side I have a model.js where I extend the metadata as described in [John Papas Angular course](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=build-apps-angular-breeze) (which is very good BTW) on Pluralsight. I add the properties (with appropriately cased names) and set the initial value to 0.0. Breeze should then 'map' the incoming value to these new properties - which it does.

```
    function registerPaymentEntity(metadataStore) {
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Payment', Payment);

        function Payment() {
            this.TotalPayment = 0.0;
            this.StandardPayment = 0.0;

            // other stuff...
        }
    }
```

However... in 1.4.11 all was ok but in 1.4.13 it appears to be truncating the decimal value and losing all the decimal places. If I send back, for example, 2500.36 it will display fine in 1.4.11 but appear as 2500.00 in 1.4.13.

At first I thought it was me applying some odd filtering to ngGrid cells but having dug into the developer tools it appears that the Breeze backing store is holding the truncated value rather than the full value.

I haven't been able to check in 1.4.12 as I can't find where to download it without having to build it from source - which requires a bit of grunt work (pun intended) that I'm not familiar with at the moment. I've looked through the source but there are a lot of changes between .11 and .13 and I haven't been able to pinpoint anything yet.

This may be a bug report rather than a "true" SO question but, on the other hand, I may be doing something wrong so am asking for a bit of clarification.

So, the question is - is anyone else experiencing a similar issue or are your readonly decimal properties OK. If so can you shed any light on what I ought to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and is now fixed in the Breeze.js GitHub repo.  This fix will also be part of the next full Breeze.js release (1.4.14) out sometime next week.

One additional note here: another bug was also fixed that may end up breaking your code. Previously, the metadataStore.namingConvention was NOT being use to convert between client and server names when 'unmapped' properties were involved; as of (1.4.14) the namingConvention IS used to convert unmapped property names ( as well as mapped prop names).